# How to make excel linked to another excel file in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, excel-2010, vba

I have 3 Excel files that are uploaded in Sharepoint 2010. In one theme every cell links to one of three Excel files. In Sharepoint without opening in Excel on desktop, is there any way to update linked data? Is there any way to run VBA?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA and external data ranges (also quoted query tables) are **not** supported by SharePoint 2010 and neither so by SharePoint 2013 while using Excel Services to view these files online.

These features are only supported if you open them within Excel itself.

Here is the complete answer from Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff595319.aspx